# Installation Error Graph tool

Tags: fedora

karnel:3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64

I'm trying to install graph tool which need cairomm-1.0. I installed separately, but  I'm not finding out by wereis or which command. 
How do I know that cairomm-1 is installed or not? 
and if it not installed how do I install it?
Please help me out

Comment: which graphics tool? are you trying to install using yum or manually?

Answer (score 0):

well I did; actually the cairomm was not isntalling. I was trying manually installing graph-tool by using the downloadable version. I did with disable the cairomm at the time of configuration. As it is not mandatory package for graph-tool to work so its doing fine with me.

any one having problem same as me do this

go to the graph tool unzipped folder by cd

do configure --disable-cairomm

hope this will work

thanks